# EasyAdmin 3: OneToMany field names not displayed on the main page

Tags: php, symfony5, easyadmin

I created two entities - Product and Packing. They are related by OneToMany connection (one Product - many Packings).
When I open the Packings list in EasyAdmin, I can see the products' names in the Packings grid.
But, if I open the Products list in EasyAdmin, I can see only the packings' ids instead of their names.
What should I do to fix this? Thanks.

```
class PackingCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
```

{
...

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        TextField::new('name'),
        AssociationField::new('product')->setLabel('Продукты'),
    ];
}
```

class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
...

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        ...
        AssociationField::new('packings')
            ->setLabel('Фасовки')
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]),
```

Comment: do you have anything in the configureFields function of the admin CRUD controllers? if so would you mind adding what's in there to your question

Comment: HoppyB, I added code to my question.

Answer (score 3):

In your Products entity you want to create a __toString() function to tell symfony how to display your entity as a string, it will chose the id by default.

In `App\Entity\Products.php`

```
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks HoppyB, but I already have such function in my entities(